# Padding Between "display:table-cell"

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is there a way to place padding or a transparent border around the "cells" when one does `display:table-cell`? I would like the background to show up through this space, so I can't just set the border to white, and `border-color:transparent` doesn't work for me for some reason. I've checked w3schools and similar sites but I haven't been able to find this particular trait.

From user *Praveen Vijayan*: http://jsfiddle.net/geymU/

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: Glad this got answered before Andrew Barber closed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `border-spacing: 10px` on the parent container.

In your case

```
#nav ul{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

You can also give top/bottom and left/right separately like `border-spacing: 10px 20px;`

Comment: The `border-spacing` property worked fine, except for the order: in Chromium browser v. 36.0.1921.0, the first value corresponds to horizontal spacing, and the second one to vertical spacing.

Answer (score 4):

The space between cells is controlled by the `border-spacing` and `border-collapse` properties in the table.

```
#nav ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 12px 6px;
}
```